# Increasing memory working set in an Azure Durable Function App (memory leak)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure infrastructure with a Node.js 14 LTS Durable Function App using an HTTP trigger, an orchestrator function and some activity functions in an Elastic Premium 1 (EP1) App Service Plan. The number of Linux instances is:

- 4 always ready instances
- 4 pre-warmed instances

I have noticed that, even if the HTTP traffic is on average constant during the days/weeks, the performance of the system decreases day by day, i.e. every day the response time of the functions is worse that the day before. In the picture below it is shown the response time of some functions of the Durable Function App:

[image]

Also the CPU percentage usage of the App Service Plan hosting the Durable Function App is increasing:

[image]

Based on some documentation that I found online, a possible reason could be a memory leak, indeed if I check the average memory working set of the Durable Function App, I see an almost constant increase:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion on how I can debug this issue?

I also tried to check some other metrics like private bytes, Gen 0, 1 and 2 garbage collections, but they are all empty:

[image]

Why the private bytes metric is zero?

Finally, every time I deploy again the infrastructure, right after the deployment everything works properly without any performance issue and the memory working set goes to the minimum level which is around 200 MB, but as the days go ahead, the performance becomes day by day worse.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of the code that causes this condition? I personally wonder if this is related to the memory leak issues observed in Node 14/16/18 over the past 1-2 years that (to my knowledge) have yet to be resolved in Node core/v8. (It’s worth noting in this vein that Node v14 has just reached the end of its maintenance period, so I would recommend separately you upgrade your execution environment as, if there is a patch issued for this, it likely won’t be propagated to v14.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I can't copy any piece of code here as for my company policy. But do you suggest any tool to use for finding memory leaks or any Azure metrics to monitor? Also, the fact that the garbage collector and private bytes metrics are always empty is due to a misconfiguration at the code level?